# C++ string returning a space when accessing a valid index containing a P

Tags: c++

I have the following assignment:

> The string "PAYPALISHIRING" is written in a zigzag pattern on a given number of rows like this: (you may want to display this pattern in a fixed font for better legibility)
>
> ```
> P   A   H   N
> A P L S I I G
> Y   I   R
> ```
>
> And then read line by line: "PAHNAPLSIIGYIR"
>
> Write the code that will take a string and make this conversion given a number of rows:
>
> `string convert(string s, int numRows);`
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: s = "PAYPALISHIRING", numRows = 3
>   Output: "PAHNAPLSIIGYIR"
>
> Example 2:
>
> Input: s = "PAYPALISHIRING", numRows = 4
>   Output: "PINALSIGYAHRPI"
>   Explanation:
>
> ```
> P     I    N
> A   L S  I G
> Y A   H R
> P     I
> ```

The following is what I tried:

```
std::string convert(std::string s, int numRows) {
        std::string answer = "";
        std::vector<int> row1_indicies;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            if (numRows % 2 == 0)
            {
                row1_indicies.push_back(numRows*i+2*i);
            }
            else
            {
                row1_indicies.push_back(numRows*i+i);
            }
            if (row1_indicies[i] > s.length())
            {
                row1_indicies.pop_back();
                break;
            }
            else if (row1_indicies[i] == s.length())
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < row1_indicies.size(); j++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    answer += s[row1_indicies[j]];
                }
                else if (i == numRows-1)
                {
                    answer += s[row1_indicies[j]+i];
                }
                else
                {
                    if (j == 0)
                    {
                        answer += s[row1_indicies[j]+i];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        answer += s[row1_indicies[j]-i];
                        answer += s[row1_indicies[j]+i];
                    }
                }  
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }

int main(){
    std::string input = "PAYPALISHIRING";
    int numRows = 4;
    std::cout << "input = " << input << ", number of rows = " << numRows << std::endl;
    std::string output = convert(input, numRows);
    std::cout << output << "    expected: PINALSIGYAHRPI" << std::endl << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My error occurs in the block:

```
else if (i == numRows-1)
{
   answer += s[row1_indicies[j]+i];
}
```

When I debug I get "PINALSIGYAHR PI". It shows /000P is being returned when that index is accessed.
I added the following check to the block:

```
else if (i == numRows-1)
{
   std::cout << std::endl << s.at(row1_indicies[j] + i) << std::endl;
   answer += s[row1_indicies[j]+i];
}
```

Output looks like:

```
input = PAYPALISHIRING, number of rows = 4

P

I

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 15) >= this->size() (which is 14)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Present your problem in the form of a [mcve] after narrowing it down to the smallest program that has this bug

Comment: We can't see how you're observing this result, but if by "space" you literally mean you see space on the screen somewhere, does that mean it's actually a null character and /000 is some literal representation of that from some debugger? We really can't tell what's going on here from the information provided.

Comment: _"I'm definitely accessing a valid index for string s"_ How do you verify that? There's no checking in the code. A quick `assert` will do the job... (or use `.at()`)

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I updated the question to include what I get with the .at() check. I'm not sure how that is possible when j=0 and i=3. It should return a 'P'.

Comment: If you change all occurrences of `[xxx]` to `.at(xxx)` then it'll throw an exception when the index is out of range instead of undefined behaviour and you can debug it more easily  e.g.:  `s[row1_indicies[j] + i]` becomes `s.at(row1_indicies.at(j) + i)`

Comment: Ok so now you know what's wrong, you can go through your algorithm line by line and work out where your assumptions are breaking down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is there

```
else
    {
     answer += s[row1_indicies[j]-i];
     answer += s[row1_indicies[j]+i];
    }
```

You need this

```
 else
    {
     answer += s[row1_indicies[j]-i];
     if(row1_indicies[j]+i < s.length()){
         answer += s[row1_indicies[j]+i];
         }
    }
```

Also add an `else if` and add an `AND`.
The `for` should look like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < row1_indicies.size(); j++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                answer += s[row1_indicies[j]];
                }
            else if (i == numRows-1 && row1_indicies[j]+i < s.length()) {
                answer += s[row1_indicies[j]+i];
                }
            else if (i == numRows-1 && row1_indicies[j]+i > s.length()) {
                return answer;
                }
            else {
                if (j == 0) {
                    answer += s[row1_indicies[j]+i];
                    }
                else {
                    answer += s[row1_indicies[j]-i];
                    if(row1_indicies[j]+i < s.length()) {
                        answer += s[row1_indicies[j]+i];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it doesn't answer your question, but why not something like this:

```
std::string convert(std::string s, int numRows)
{
    std::vector <string> rows;
    for(int i=0; i<numRows; i++)
    {
        rows.push_back(""); //every row is empty at the beginning
    }

    int repeatEvery = numRows + (numRows - 2); //numRows-2 says how many elements are on the diagonally (without the end and the beginning of the vertical columns)
    int addRepeatValue = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
    {
        //going down the column
        rows[i % repeatEvery] += s[i];

        //upper right
        if(i>= numRows-1 + addRepeatValue) // (numRows-1) + k*repeatEvery
        {
            for(int j=(numRows-1 + addRepeatValue-1)%(numRows-1); j>0; j--)
            {
                i++;
                if(i == s.length()) break; //if it is already end of data then don't finish
                rows[j] += s[i];
            }
            addRepeatValue += repeatEvery;
        }
        if(i == s.length()) break; //if it is already end of data then don't finish
    }

    string result="";
    for(int i=0; i<rows.size(); i++) result += rows[i];
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you try it on paper, you can easily figure out how to compute indices.

- If numRows is 1, returns the string as it.
- For top and bottom row, index increase by `2 * (numRows - 1)`.
- For any row, the initial index is the index of the row.
- For any row in between, increment alternate between:

  - `2 * (numRows - index - 1)`
  - `2 * numRows`.

Thus an algorithm like this will works:

```
std::string convert(std::string s, int numRows)
{
    if (numRows <= 1) { return s; } // Required to avoid an infinite loop below

    int offsetTotal = (numRows - 1) * 2;
    int len = s.length();

    std::string result;

    for (int row = 0; row < numRows; ++row)
    {
        int index = row;
        int offset = 2 * row;

        while (index < len)
        {
            result += s[index];

            if (offset != offsetTotal) 
            { 
                offset = offsetTotal - offset; 
            }

            index += offset;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

And if you want multiline output, an algorithm similar to this would do:

```
std::string convert(std::string s, int numRows)
{
    if (numRows <= 1) { return s; }

    int bloc_size = (numRows - 1) * 2;
    int len = s.length();
    int bloc_count = (len + bloc_size - 1) / bloc_size;
    int width = bloc_count * (numRows - 1) + 1;
    int size = width * numRows;

    std::vector<char> data(size, ' ');
    for (int i = width - 1; i < size; i += width) { data[i] = '\n'; }

    std::vector<int> indexes;

    bool down = true;
    int index = 0;
    int row = 0;
    for (auto ch : s)
    {
        indexes.push_back(index);

        data[index] = ch;

        if (++row == numRows) 
        { 
            down = !down; 
            row = 1;
        }

        index += down ? width : 1 - width;
    }

    return { data.begin(), data.end() };
}
```